# ¿Por qué me marca un error en filter cuando hago esta llamada con Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Lo que pasa es que creé un `controller` para hacer llamadas a un *JSON* y funciona con un *JSON* que encontré en internet, pero con el que lo necesito usar provoca un error en el `filter`:

Es este:

```
angular.module("liverpoolapp",["ngStorage"])
.controller("primerControlador",function($scope,$http,$localStorage){
    $scope.posts = [];
    $http.get(
        "http://www.liverpool.com.mx/tienda?s=sala&d3106047a194921c01969dfdec083925=json"
    ).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.posts = data;
    }).error(function(err){});
    $scope.grabar = function(){
        $localStorage.busqueda = $scope.busqueda;
    }
});
```

El código lo pueden ver aquí:

Este es el proyecto con un enlace *JSON* que encontré en internet: http://www.mukizo.com/test/v6/

... y este es el mismo pero con el enlace que necesito que funcione:
http://www.mukizo.com/test/v7/

En la consola se ve que provoca un error:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [filter:notarray]

¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿El *JSON* es válido?

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que el primer link devuelve un array de objetos a diferencia del segundo, que sólo devuelve un objeto y es por ello el error *notarray*.

Recuerda que estás declarando a `$scope.posts` como una arreglo. Para solventar eso, no asignes sino haz un `push`.

```
angular.module("liverpoolapp",["ngStorage"])
   .controller("primerControlador",function($scope,$http,$localStorage){
      $scope.posts = [];
      $http.get("http://www.liverpool.com.mx/tienda?s=sala&d3106047a194921c01969dfdec083925=json")
      .success(function(data){
            $scope.posts.push(data);
       })
       .error(function(err){
       });

       $scope.grabar = function(){
       $localStorage.busqueda = $scope.busqueda;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de César Gómez.
Lo que me gustaría recordarte sería usar la notación de arreglo para aquello de la inyección de dependencias. Tú tienes ahora:

```
//Lo demás
angular.module("liverpoolapp",["ngStorage"])
.controller("primerControlador",function($scope,$http,$localStorage){
   //El contenido
});
```

Te recomiendo:

```
//Lo demás
angular.module("liverpoolapp",["ngStorage"])
.controller("primerControlador",["$scope", "$http", "$localStorage", function($scope,$http,$localStorage){
//El contenido
}]);
```

No sé si uses una especie de herramienta como Grunt para hacer tu publicación de producción, pero sin la notación de arreglo, si haces una reducción (*minification*) del código, vas a tener problemas.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es la que comenta el amigo *Cesar*, de todas formas al igual que el amigo *Alex*, les dejó algunas buenas prácticas que se pueden aplicar a ese código.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('liverpoolApp',["ngStorage"]);
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('liverpoolApp')

.controller('NombreDelControlador', function($localStorage, nombreDelServicioSevice) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.getPosts() = getPosts;

    vm.posts = [];
    vm.posts.push(nombreDelServicioSevice.getPostsTiendaLiverpool);

    function saveData () {
        //Aqui guardas los datos
    }
});
```

**service.js**

```
angular.module('liverpoolApp')

.service('nombreDelServicioSevice', function() {

    nombreDelServicioService = this;

    //Aqui declaras los metodos publicos de tu servicio 
    // que seran accesibles por el resto de la applicacion.
    nombreDelServicioService.getArticulosTiendaLiverpool;

    return nombreDelServicioService;

    //Aqui haces la declaracion de los metodos tanto publicos como privados.
    function getPostsTiendaLiverpool() {
        return $http
         .get(
          "http://www.liverpool.com.mx/tienda?s=sala&d3106047a194921c01969dfdec083925=json"
         )
         .then(onGetArticulosTiendaLiverpoolSuccess, onGetArticulosTiendaLiverpoolError);

        function onGetArticulosTiendaLiverpoolSuccess(respuesta) {
            return respuesta.data;
        }
        function onGetArticulosTiendaLiverpoolError(error) {
            console.log('Aqui pones las acciones que tu quieras hacer en caso de error');
        }
    }
});
```